# Why is EF core datacontext updating foreign key object collections?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

The following correctly updates the "review" object but also updates all other review objects that had the same original value of 'status'.

```
review=_context.Review.Where(q=>q.id==1).Include(q=>q.Status).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
review.Status.Status1= "approved";
```

so review with id=1 gets properly updated from "pending"
but so does review with id=2 if it also had "pending".

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the Status1 property of a Status record rather than assigning a different status to the review.

For instance lets say you have 3 statuses, "Pending", "Approved", and "Rejected". This would be 3 status records. A Review has a Status ID which points to a Status record. Your EF review entity also has a Status reference.

Given the following records:

StatusId: 1, Status1: "Pending"

StatusId: 2, Status1: "Approved"

StatusId: 3, Status1: "Rejected"

You may have a Review record with a StatusID of 1. ("Pending")
If you go review.Status.Status1 = "Approved" you are telling EF to update the status1 text field of record #1 to "Approved". Every review associated with StatusID #1 will say "Approved".

What you really want to do is point the review at Status ID #2.

So at a base level, it should look something like:

```
review.Status = context.Statuses.Single(x => x.Status1 == "Approved");
```

This tells EF to associate that review with the status matching Approved. Behind the scenes what EF will do is update the StatusID on your Review record to "2". Now there are more efficient ways to assign a status like this, but it should help you understand the reference issue you are currently experiencing.